Python Playwright. Python is stuck at async operation
I'm trying to create a simple 'One Time Set Up' that will be used automatically before each test. The purpose is to initialize the playwright in 'One Time Set Up' and then pass the test. During run/debug test stuck on line await one_time_setup.goto("https://github.com") but navigation itself successfully happening.
import pytest
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


class LocalFixture:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
    async def one_time_setup(self):
        playwright = await async_playwright().start()
        browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = await browser.new_context()
        page = await context.new_page()
        await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/")

        yield page

        await page.close()
        await context.close()
        await browser.close()
        await playwright.stop()


class TestExample(LocalFixture):
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_example(self, one_time_setup):
        await one_time_setup.goto("https://github.com")
        print("done") 

pytest.ini
[pytest] asyncio_mode = auto

requirements.txt
playwright==1.44.0 
pytest==8.2.2 
pytest-asyncio==0.23.7
pytest-base-url==2.1.0 
pytest-playwright==0.5.0

I do appreciate your time and input!
